# Unity3D VSCode debugging on Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

It seems like Unity3D VSCode debugging already works on OSX?
[Debugging in Unity (C#) + Visual Studio Code Work on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957958/debugging-in-unity-c-visual-studio-code-work-on-os-x)

But not on Windows yet because no mono support for Windows?
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ

Has anyone found a way to get Unity3D VSCode debugging working on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: i will try this next
https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/src

Comment: this urge to install osx is strange

Comment: Why not just install the community edition of Visual Studio and then use the Visual Studio Tools for Unity?

Comment: @Bart's suggestion is the same as mine. Unity 5 works very nicely with VS community and VS 2015 RC

Comment: i do already have visual studio and visual studio tools working thanks for the suggestions, but since i use vscode instead and vscode debugging does work on mac i am trying to get it to work on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unity provided an extension to get this working

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/vs-code-unity-debugger-extension-preview.369775/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug

Answer (score 1):

Currently .NET debugging is based on Mono - which is only available for Linux and Mac OS X.  As a result for debugging on Windows it's better to use Visual Studio Community.

Sean McBreen
VS Code Team Member